# Iterating over array of object in Angular 2+ fro each Object property use separate <tr>

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am trying to solve this senario where I have to use table and achive below

Array of objects

```
[
    {
        name:'Jhon',
        email:'jhon@gmail.com',
        add1:'addr line 1',
        add2:'addr line 1'
    },

    ...
]
```

Should be shown like

```
<table>
    Name == should be in one tr => td

    email == should be in one tr => td

    add1 and add2 == should be in one tr => 2 td's

</td>
```

I am not able to achive this using *ngFor on tr can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Seeing your requirement and structure, are you sure you should use Table ?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over tbody tag like this

```
 <tbody *ngFor="let a of arr">
    <tr><td>{{a.name}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: If you don't want create "extra-elements" use ng-container https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue

Comment: Yes ng-container is also a nice way of grouping elements neva used in practical though but yes it offers zero alteration to existing styles.

Comment: Thanks eliseo ng-continer that is solves it precisely.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index">
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
</tr> 
<tr *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index">
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
</tr> 
<tr *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index">
        <td>{{user.add1}}</td>
        <td>{{user.add2}}</td>
</tr>
```

The Html should look like this according to your QUESTION!.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border cellspacing="0">
<tbody *ngFor="let a of data">
<tr>
   <td>name</td>
  <td>{{a.name}}</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
  <td>{{a.email}}</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>Address</td>
  <td>{{a.add1}}</td>
   <td>{{a.add2}}</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="3" style="background-color:black" ></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve it in both ways Using *ngFor on tbody and using ng-container

I found ng-container is more appropriate way of doing this as tbody was creating multiple body in table where ng-container was generating normal tr elements as specified.

```
<tbody *ngFor="let emp of Employees">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">{{emp.name}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">{{emp.email}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{emp.address1}}</td>
    <td>{{emp.address2}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

<ng-container *ngFor="let emp of Employees">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">{{emp.name}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">{{emp.email}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{emp.address1}}</td>
    <td>{{emp.address2}}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```